# Odd ANTLR4 error handling behavior with very simply (trivial) behavior

Tags: antlr4

Given the below super simple grammar:

```
ddlStatement
    :   defineStatement
    ;

defineStatement
    :   'define' tableNameToken=Identifier ';'?
    ;
```

and the input "add 1 to bob"

I would expect to get an error. However, the parser matches the "defineStatement" rule with a missing "define" token. The following Listener will fire

```
 @Override
 public void exitDefineStatement(DDLParser.DefineStatementContext ctx) {
    log.info(MessageFormat.format("Defining {0}", ctx.tableNameToken.getText()));
 }
```

and log "Defining add".

I can assign 'define' to a variable and test that variable for NULL but that seems like work I shouldn't have to do.

BTW if the grammar becomes more complete - specifically with the addition of alternatives to the ddlStatement rule - error handling works as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

This ANTLR's error recovery in action.

In many cases, it's VERY beneficial for ANTLR to assume either a missing token, or ignore a token, if it allows parsing to continue.  The missing "define" token should have been reported as an error.

Without this capability, ANTLR would frequently get "stumped" at the first sign of problems.  With this, ANTLR is saying "Well, if I assume X, then I can make sense of your input. So I'm assuming X and reporting that as an error so I can continue on.

(Filling a few details to get this to build)

```
grammar Test
    ;

ddlStatement: defineStatement;

defineStatement: 'define' tableNameToken = Identifier ';'?;

Identifier: [a-zA-Z]+;
Number:     [0-9]+;
WS:         [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

if I run antlr on this and compile the Java output.  The following command:

```
echo "add 1 to bob" | grun Test ddlStatement -gui
```

yields the error:

```
line 1:0 missing 'define' at 'add'
```

and produces the parse tree:

[image]

The highlighted node is the error node in the tree.

The reason it stops after "add" is that input (assuming a missing "define", would be a `ddlStatement`

ANTLR will stop processing input once it has recognized your stop rule.

To get it to "pay attention" to the entire input, add an `EOF` token to your start rule:

```
grammar Test
    ;

ddlStatement: defineStatement EOF;

defineStatement: 'define' tableNameToken = Identifier ';'?;

Identifier: [a-zA-Z]+;
Number:     [0-9]+;
WS:         [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

gives these errors:

```
line 1:0 missing 'define' at 'add'
line 1:4 mismatched input '1' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}
```

and this tree:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to say that the token is absolutely required?

Comment: You have said that it's absolutely required.  The Parser should have reported an error stating that it was missing the "define" token.  ANTLR is considering it an Error, it's just that ErrorRecovery is kicking in to attempt to continue parsing the input and possibly reporting additional errors. You wouldn't want it to stop at the first error it encountered.  It would be very irritating.  You should have had an error reported and the resulting tree should contain an error Node.

Comment: Use the `org.antlr.v4.runtime.BailErrorStrategy` to stop the parser where a token is `absolutely required`.  Two reasonable use scenarios (two-stage parsing, silent validation) are discussed in the class Javadoc. Implement using `myparser.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());`